# CSS Selector by RGB Color

Tags: node.js, colors, css-selectors

Via CSS selector, I try to select a text based on the RGB color.

Test URL: https://santis.be/boutique/produit/Klorane-Capil-Sh-Sec-Ortie-Spray-150ml-Nf

My CSS selector is returning null:

```
document.querySelector('.detail-produit__content__content__vignette-produit__content__quantite-desc__stock > span[style="color:rgb(112, 182, 44)"]')
```

Where am I wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Could you use a snippet to show the code here?

Comment: not sure to understand correctly. here I'm using the console in Google Chrome, where I run my query in the console document.querySelector('.detail-produit__content__content__vignette-produit__content__quantite-desc__stock > span[style="color:rgb(112, 182, 44)"]') on the Test URL

Comment: Hi @Henri. It's tricky to read code in comments. My suggestion is that you **[edit]** your question, and then click on the button for "HTML/JS/CSS Snippet" and include your code that way. Two benefits: (a) it's then here in the question, so people don't need to visit your site (which may change), and (b) it's smaller code, focused precisely on your problem, so it's less code for people to dig through. This makes things much easier for answerers, so they'll be better able to help you.

Comment: I understand your point, you are totally right. But, how do I have to add the HTML source of the webpage to the snippet code? copy/paste? Sorry for stupid question, first time I have to use it